# awk histogram in buckets

Tags: awk, grouping

Consider I have a following file..

```
1 a
1 b
1 a
1 c
1 a
2 a
2 d
2 a
2 d
```

I want to have a histogram within a bucket... for example if bucket is 1 then the output will be

```
a 3
b 1
c 1
a 2
d 2
```

for bucket 2... we have

```
a 5
b 1
c 1
d 2
```

I want to do it with awk and I literally stuck... 
here is my code:

```
awk '
    {A[$1]} count [$2]++ 
    {for(i in A) {print i,A[i]}
    }' test
```

Any help?

Thanks,

Amir.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit** Adding a size_of_bucket variable.

```
awk -v "size_of_bucket=2" '
  {
    bucket = int(($1-1)/size_of_bucket);
    A[bucket","$2]++;
  }
  END {
    for (i in A) {
      print i, A[i];
    }
  }
'
```

Comment: thank you very much... that actually work for time window of 1. No I need to figure out how I can slide the time windows with different sizes... (the number if the first column is time)

Comment: Ok. I've added a size of bucket variable that you can tweak. Don't forget to accept my answer if it helps you.

Comment: it is correct.. but if you want to having a sliding window you should do it like this .. for window size 3

Comment: it is correct.. but if you want to having a sliding window you should do it like this .. for window size 3

        awk 'BEGIN {
            A[""]=0;
        }
        {
            A[$1" "$2]++;
            A[$1-1" "$2]++;
            A[$1-2" "$2]++;
        }
        END {
            for (i in A) {
                if (i != "") {
                    print i, A[i];
               }
           }
       }' 

thanks again for your help

Comment: I moved the bucket size variable to an awk option and removed the BEGIN block -- you don't need to predefine an array, you just start using it.