# Create bins with awk histogram-like

Tags: bash, unix, dataframe, awk, grouping

Here's my input file :

```
1.37987
1.21448
0.624999
1.28966
1.77084
1.088
1.41667
```

I would like to create bins of a size of my choice to get histogram-like output, e.g. something like this for 0.1 bins, starting from 0 :

```
0 0.1 0
...
0.5 0.6 0
0.6 0.7 1
...
1.0 1.1 1
1.1 1.2 0
1.2 1.3 2
1.3 1.4 1
...
```

My file is too big for R, so I'm looking for an awk solution (also open to anything else that I can understand, as I'm still a Linux beginner).

This was sort of already answered in this post : [awk histogram in buckets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948586/awk-histogram-in-buckets) but the solution is not working for me.

Comment: In what way is that answer "not working" for you?

Comment: I get nonsense as output if I input my example table (and I'm not good enough to figure out what's actually going on)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is also possible :

```
awk -v size=0.1 
  '{ b=int($1/size); a[b]++; bmax=b>bmax?b:bmax; bmin=b<bmin?b:bmin }
   END { for(i=bmin;i<=bmax;++i) print i*size,(i+1)*size,a[i] }' <file>
```

It essentially does the same as the solution of EdMorton, but starts printing buckets from the minimum value which is default `0`. It essentially takes negative numbers into account.

Answer (score 8):

This should be very close if not exactly right. Consider it a starting point at least and verify/figure out the math yourself (in particular decide/verify which bucket(s) an exact boundary match like `0.2` should go into - 0.1 to 0.2 and/or 0.2 to 0.3?):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { delta = (delta == "" ? 0.1 : delta) }
{
    bucketNr = int(($0+delta) / delta)
    cnt[bucketNr]++
    numBuckets = (numBuckets > bucketNr ? numBuckets : bucketNr)
}
END {
    for (bucketNr=1; bucketNr<=numBuckets; bucketNr++) {
        end = beg + delta
        printf "%0.1f %0.1f %d\n", beg, end, cnt[bucketNr]
        beg = end
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
0.0 0.1 0
0.1 0.2 0
0.2 0.3 0
0.3 0.4 0
0.4 0.5 0
0.5 0.6 0
0.6 0.7 1
0.7 0.8 0
0.8 0.9 0
0.9 1.0 0
1.0 1.1 1
1.1 1.2 0
1.2 1.3 2
1.3 1.4 1
1.4 1.5 1
1.5 1.6 0
1.6 1.7 0
1.7 1.8 1
```

Note that you can assign the bucket delta size on the command line, 0.1 is just the default value:

```
$ awk -v delta='0.3' -f tst.awk file
0.0 0.3 0
0.3 0.6 0
0.6 0.9 1
0.9 1.2 1
1.2 1.5 4
1.5 1.8 1

$ awk -v delta='0.5' -f tst.awk file
0.0 0.5 0
0.5 1.0 1
1.0 1.5 5
1.5 2.0 1
```

Comment: Testing it right now but it seems really good ! It's super fast too, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot, I'm not that good at awk (yet ?). Any idea about how to handle negative values as well with this code ? For now they don't seem to be taken into account.

Comment: It's very important when you ask a question to include your requirements in the question and make sure your sample input/output is truly representative of your real data. You said you wanted to create bins starting from zero and showed only positive numbers in your data so that;s what you got a solution for. It's extremely frustrating when trying to help someone to then hear "oh but that's not REALLY what my data looks like....". Edit your question to state what it is you're really trying to do and show that in your eg in/out. The solution will be trivial but we can't keep peeling the onion.

Comment: Sorry sir for the frustration. It's more by curiosity/education/future use that I asked for negative values. For my current problem, your solution is completly fine ! It's just that I might run into this problem someday...

Answer (score 3):

Here is my stab at solving this with Awk.

To run: `awk -f belowscript.awk inputfile`

```
BEGIN {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc";
    delta = (delta == "") ? 0.1 : delta;
};

/^-?([0-9][0-9]*|[0-9]*(\.[0-9][0-9]*))/ {
    # Special case the [-delta - 0] case so it doesn't bin in the [0-delta] bin
    fractBin=$1/delta
    if (fractBin < 0 && int(fractBin) == fractBin)
        fractBin = fractBin+1
    prefix = (fractBin <= 0 && int(fractBin) == 0) ? "-" : ""
    bins[prefix int(fractBin)]++
}

END {
    for (var in bins)
    {
        srange = sprintf("%0.2f",delta * ((var >= 0) ? var : var-1))
        erange = sprintf("%0.2f",delta * ((var >= 0) ? var+1 : var))
        print srange " " erange " " bins[var]
    }
}
```

Some notes:

- I added support for providing the bin size on the command line like Ed Morton did.
- It only prints the bins that contain something
- Which bin an exact match goes in - the smaller or the larger bin naturally with this approach negated when going negative, and required tweaking to make it consistent.
- the 0 boundary needed special casing for those numbers in the first negative bin, since there is no such number as -0. Awk's associative arrays use strings for keys, so "-0" was possible, and with @ind_num_asc sort order for the for loop, seems to sort the -0 properly - though this may not be portable.

Comment: Seems like you're speaking Awk with a Perl accent

Comment: More like speaking Awk with a C/C++ accent heh, but I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with Python

```
# draw histogram in command line with Python
# 
# usage: $ cat datafile.txt | python this_script.py [nbins] [nscale]
# The input should be one column of numbers to be piped in.  
#
# forked from https://gist.github.com/bgbg

from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import numpy as np

def asciihist(it, bins=10, minmax=None, str_tag='',
              scale_output=30, generate_only=False, print_function=print):
    """Create an ASCII histogram from an interable of numbers.
    Author: Boris Gorelik boris@gorelik.net. based on  http://econpy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pytrix/pytrix.py
    License: MIT
    """
    ret = []
    itarray = np.asanyarray(it)
    if minmax == 'auto':
        minmax = np.percentile(it, [5, 95])
        if minmax[0] == minmax[1]:
            # for very ugly distributions
            minmax = None
    if minmax is not None:
        # discard values that are outside minmax range
        mn = minmax[0]
        mx = minmax[1]
        itarray = itarray[itarray >= mn]
        itarray = itarray[itarray <= mx]
    if itarray.size:
        total = len(itarray)
        counts, cutoffs = np.histogram(itarray, bins=bins)
        cutoffs = cutoffs[1:]
        if str_tag:
            str_tag = '%s ' % str_tag
        else:
            str_tag = ''
        if scale_output is not None:
            scaled_counts = counts.astype(float) / counts.sum() * scale_output
        else:
            scaled_counts = counts

        if minmax is not None:
            ret.append('Trimmed to range (%s - %s)' % (str(minmax[0]), str(minmax[1])))
        for cutoff, original_count, scaled_count in zip(cutoffs, counts, scaled_counts):
            ret.append("{:s}{:>8.2f} |{:<7,d} | {:s}".format(
                str_tag,
                cutoff,
                original_count,
                "*" * int(scaled_count))
                       )
        ret.append(
            "{:s}{:s} |{:s} | {:s}".format(
                str_tag,
                '-' * 8,
                '-' * 7,
                '-' * 7
            )
        )
        ret.append(
            "{:s}{:>8s} |{:<7,d}".format(
                str_tag,
                'N=',
                total
            )
        )
    else:
        ret = []
    if not generate_only:
        for line in ret:
            print_function(line)
    ret = '\n'.join(ret)
    return ret


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    nbins=30
    if len(sys.argv) >= 2:
        nbins = int(sys.argv[1])
    nscale=400
    if len(sys.argv) == 3:
        nscale = int(sys.argv[2])
    
    
    dataIn =[]
    
    for line in sys.stdin:
        if line.strip() != '':
           dataIn.append( float(line)) 
    
    asciihist(dataIn, bins=nbins, scale_output=nscale, minmax=None, str_tag='BIN');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73137125/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)