# Create histogram like bins for a range including negative numbers

Tags: awk

I have numbers in a range from `-4` to `4`, including `0`, as in

```
-0.526350041828112
-0.125648350883331
0.991377353361933
1.079241128983
1.06322905224238
1.17477528478982
-0.0651086035371559
0.818471811380787
0.0355593553368815
```

I need to create histogram like buckets, and have being trying to use this

```
BEGIN { delta = (delta == "" ? 0.1 : delta) }
{
    bucketNr = int(($0+delta) / delta)
    cnt[bucketNr]++
    numBuckets = (numBuckets > bucketNr ? numBuckets : bucketNr)
}
END {
    for (bucketNr=1; bucketNr<=numBuckets; bucketNr++) {
        end = beg + delta
        printf "%0.1f %0.1f %d\n", beg, end, cnt[bucketNr]
        beg = end
    }
}
```

from  [Create bins with awk histogram-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49737975/create-bins-with-awk-histogram-like)

The output would look like

```
-2.4 -2.1 8
-2.1 -1.8 25
-1.8 -1.5 108
-1.5 -1.2 298
-1.2 -0.9 773
-0.9 -0.6 1067
-0.6 -0.3 1914
-0.3 0.0 4174
0.0 0.3 3969
0.3 0.6 2826
0.6 0.9 1460
0.9 1.2 752
1.2 1.5 396
1.5 1.8 121
1.8 2.1 48
2.1 2.4 13
2.4 2.7 1
2.7 3.0 1
```

I'm thinking I would have to run this 2x, one with `delta` let's say `0.3` and another with `delta` `-0.3`, and cat the two together.

But I'm not sure this intuition is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
BEGIN { delta = (delta == "" ? 0.1 : delta) }
{
    bucketNr = int(($0<0?$0-delta:$0)/delta)
    cnt[bucketNr]++
    maxBucket = (maxBucket > bucketNr ? maxBucket : bucketNr)
    minBucket = (minBucket < bucketNr ? minBucket : bucketNr)
}
END {
    beg = minBucket*delta
    for (bucketNr=minBucket; bucketNr<=maxBucket; bucketNr++) {
        end = beg + delta
        printf "%0.1f %0.1f %d\n", beg, end, cnt[bucketNr]
        beg = end
    }
}
```

It's basically the code you posted + handling negative numbers.

Comment: Upvote for using and fixing the OP's code and not creating something new!