# how to calculate occurrence of values based on user defined binning

Tags: bash, awk

List of values extracted using awk:

```
-2.2xx
-4.2xx
-3.4xx
-5.3xx
-1.3xx
-1.2xx
-1.4xx
-0.8xx
```

Expected output:

```
-1.0          1
-1.0 to -2.0    3
-2.1 to -3.0    1
-3.1 to -4.0    1
-4.0          2
```

```
grep -i 'VIO' $FILE | awk '$5 < -1 { print $5;}' | uniq -c
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/49737975/12957340

Comment: Thank You loads ! Yes, this is most helpful.

Comment: You'll have to make some tweaks to handle the negative numbers; I'll post a modified version of the answer that should (hopefully) work for your actual use-case

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create bins with awk histogram-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49737975/create-bins-with-awk-histogram-like)

Comment: I don't know what these `xx` are but if they represent digits you could try something like `datamash bin:1 1 < data.txt | datamash -sg 1 count 1`. And if they are actual `x` characters: `datamash getnum:d 1 < data.txt | datamash bin:1 1 | datamash -sg 1 count 1`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make some changes to [this excellent answer by @Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49738167/12957340) to handle the negative numbers, e.g.

Test data (also includes some positive numbers):

```
-2.2xx
-4.2xx
-3.4xx
-5.3xx
-1.3xx
-1.2xx
-1.4xx
-0.8xx
3.3xx
4xx
```

Potential solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    delta = (delta == "" ? 1 : delta)
}

{
    gsub("xx", "", $0) # remove this line if you don't have literal "xx" in your input data
    bucketNr = (int($0) <= 0 ? int($0) - 1 : int($0))
    cnt[bucketNr]++
    numBuckets = (numBuckets > bucketNr ? numBuckets : bucketNr)
    min = ($0 < min ? $0 : min)
}

END {
    beg = min
    for (bucketNr = int(min); bucketNr <= numBuckets; bucketNr++) {
        end = beg + delta
        printf "%d %d %d\n", beg, end, cnt[bucketNr]
        beg = end
    }
}' test.txt
-5 -4 1
-4 -3 1
-3 -2 1
-2 -1 3
-1 0 1
0 0 0
0 1 0
1 2 0
2 3 1
3 4 1
```

Comment: Thank You for the updated code to handle -ve numbers. I modify the following: replace %d with %2.2f to display -ve numbers up to 2 decimal.

Comment: The code seems to work but there is some miscalculation: example list of numbers ranges from -0.52xx to -3.88xx gives the results with buckets -3.88 to -2.88 and continue down to -0.88 but the last bucket -0.88 to 0.12 is 0 which is incorrect. Any comment is greatly appreciated.