# AWK new line sorting

Tags: awk

I have a script that sorts numbers:

```
{
    if ($1 <= 9) xd++
    else if ($1 > 9 && $1 <= 19) xd1++
    else if ($1 > 19 && $1 <= 29) xd2++
    else if ($1 > 29 && $1 <= 39) xd3++
    else if ($1 > 39 && $1 <= 49) xd4++
    else if ($1 > 49 && $1 <= 59) xd5++
    else if ($1 > 59 && $1 <= 69) xd6++
    else if ($1 > 69 && $1 <= 79) xd7++
    else if ($1 > 79 && $1 <= 89) xd8++
    else if ($1 > 89 && $1 <= 99) xd9++
    else if ($1 == 100) xd10++
    } END {
    print "0-9 : "xd, "10-19 : " xd1, "20-29 : " xd2, "30-39 : " xd3, "40-49 : " xd4, "50-59 : " xd5, "60-69 : " xd6, "70-79 : " xd7, "80-89 : " xd8,  "90-99 : " xd9,  "100 : " xd10
    }
```

output:

```
$ cat xd1 | awk -f script.awk
0-9 : 16 10-19 : 4 20-29 :  30-39 : 2 40-49 : 1 50-59 : 1 60-69 : 1 70-79 : 1 80-89 : 1 90-99 : 1 100 : 2
```

how to make that every tenth was on a new line?

like this:

```
0-9 : 16
10-19 : 4 
20-29 :
30-39 : 2
```

print with \n doesn't work

additionally:

in the top ten I have 16 numbers, how can I get this information using the "+" sign

like this:

```
0-9 : 16 ++++++++++++++++
10-19 : 4 ++++
20-29 :
30-39 : 2 ++
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide concise, testable sample input (the contents of that `xd1` file and expected output given that input so we can help you with the question you asked and your original script (you don't need all those if-else's and hard-coded values in the print statement).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [awk histogram in buckets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948586/awk-histogram-in-buckets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we rewrite the current code to use an array to keep track of counts, we can then use a simple `for` loop to print the results on individual lines, eg:

```
    {      if ($1 <=  9) xd[0]++
      else if ($1 <= 19) xd[1]++
      else if ($1 <= 29) xd[2]++
      else if ($1 <= 39) xd[3]++
      else if ($1 <= 49) xd[4]++
      else if ($1 <= 59) xd[5]++
      else if ($1 <= 69) xd[6]++
      else if ($1 <= 79) xd[7]++
      else if ($1 <= 89) xd[8]++
      else if ($1 <= 99) xd[9]++
      else               xd[10]++
    }
END { for (i=0;i<=9;i++)
          print (i*10) "-" (i*10)+9, ":", xd[i]
      print "100 :", xd[10]
    }
```

At this point we could also replace the 1st part of the script with a comparable `for` loop, eg:

```
    { for (i=0;i<=9;i++)
          if ($1 <= (i*10)+9) {
             xd[i]++
             next
          }
      xd[10]++
    }
END { for (i=0;i<=9;i++)
          print (i*10) "-" (i*10)+9, ":", xd[i]
      print "100 :", xd[10]
    }
```

As for the additional requirement to print a variable number of `+` on the end of each line we can add a function (`prt()`) to generate the variable number of `+`:

```
function prt(n   ,x) {
   x=""
   if (n) {
      x=sprintf("%*s",n," ")
      gsub(/ /,"+",x)
   }
   return x
}
    { for (i=0;i<=9;i++)
          if ($1 <= (i*10)+9) {
             xd[i]++
             next
          }
      xd[10]++
    }
END { for (i=0;i<=9;i++)
          print (i*10) "-" (i*10)+9, ":", xd[i], prt(xd[i])
      print "100 :", xd[10], prt(xd[10])
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> how to make that every tenth was on a new line?

Inform GNU `AWK` that you want `OFS` (output field separator) to be newline, consider following simple example

```
awk 'BEGIN{x=1;y=2;z=3}END{print "x is " x, "y is " y, "z is " z}' emptyfile
```

gives output

```
x is 1 y is 2 z is 3
```

whilst

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\n";x=1;y=2;z=3}END{print "x is " x, "y is " y, "z is " z}' emptyfile
```

gives output

```
x is 1
y is 2
z is 3
```

Explanation: `OFS` value (default: space) is used for joining arguments of `print`. If you want to know more about `OFS` then read [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to hard-code in 10-buckets like that :

> ```
> jot -r 300 1 169 | mawk '
>
> BEGIN { _+=(_+=_^=_<_)*_*_ } { ++___[_<(__=int(($!!_)/_))?_:__] }
> END   { 
>         ____ = sprintf("%*s", NR, _)
>                   gsub(".","+",____)
>
>    for(__=_-_;__<=_;__++) { 
>
>        printf(" [%3.f %-6s] : %5.f %.*s\n",__*_,+__==+_?"+   "\
>                : " , " __*_--+_++, ___[__], ___[__], ____) } }'
> ```

```
 [  0 , 9   ] :    16 ++++++++++++++++
 [ 10 , 19  ] :    17 +++++++++++++++++
 [ 20 , 29  ] :    16 ++++++++++++++++
 [ 30 , 39  ] :    19 +++++++++++++++++++
 [ 40 , 49  ] :    14 ++++++++++++++
 [ 50 , 59  ] :    18 ++++++++++++++++++
 [ 60 , 69  ] :    18 ++++++++++++++++++
 [ 70 , 79  ] :    16 ++++++++++++++++
 [ 80 , 89  ] :    20 ++++++++++++++++++++
 [ 90 , 99  ] :    19 +++++++++++++++++++
 [100 +     ] :   127 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                      ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                      +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```